# How to optimize sum in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter

i have a code to sum total cash from transaction like this,

```
public function get_total_cash($date_from, $date_to){
        $filtered_order = array('Ordered', 'Validated','Awaiting Packing','Packing Process','Ready to Ship','Shipped','Completed');
        $op_status = array('settlement','capture');

        $this->db->select('CAST(SUM(op_total) AS int) as total');
        $this->db->from("(dashboard_sales)");
        $this->db->where('order_date >=', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime($date_from)));
        $this->db->where('order_date <=', date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($date_to)));
        $this->db->where_in('order_status',$filtered_order);
        $this->db->where_in('op_status',$op_status);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result()[0]->total;
    }
```

but the problem is that the transactions on my website have been overwhelming and when I extracted the code it became long. Transactions on my database are more than 25 thousand data.

how to make the sum process is more optimize in my case?

Comment: Do you have index on your database tables?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza nope, what is the usefulness of indexing?

Comment: indexing is a data structure which improves the data retrieval operation

Comment: check here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-create-index/

Comment: just an fyi `$query->result()[0]->total;` is functionally equivalent to this `$query->row()->total`. the latter is cleaner imo.

Answer (score 0):

Without detailed knowledge of your database structure I would suggest to write this codeigniter query into an SQL Query.

Use the EXPLAIN keyword to see the execution plan of the query via phpmyadmin, mysqlworkbench, the tool you are more familiar with. 
As this is a fairly easy query I assume you are missing indexes on fields from your where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Build a non-clustered index on your used columns like this :

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex
    ON dashboard_sales(op_total, order_date)
```

Check your Query plan before and after the creation of the index, you will see a difference. You can choose to include or not the op_total column, test your index and see in the plan.

Adding an index will reduce the number of scan in your clustered index, with EXPLAIN you can see the number of scan on the operator.

Comment: `NONCLUSTERED` is not a keyword in MySQL.

Comment: Ho, I'm doing too much T-SQL :(

Answer (score 0):

make group by primary key in your query and add index in your table so Transactions more faster.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
ALTER TABLE dashboard_sales
    ADD INDEX(order_status, op_status, order_date);
```

If you need further assistance, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE dashboard_sales`, the size of the table, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`